# Sprig - Filter entries by custom field checkbox values, separate values as well as all values

Tags: search, filter, query, checkboxes, plugin-sprig

I am having a question regarding Sprig.
I do want to filter my entries for values that are defined in a dropdown field (example below is simplified).
It does work to the point where I want to filter all entries for all values, on page load all single checkboxes should be checked as well as the `all` checkbox.
The problem is that Sprigs AJAX request sends a single request for each single filter e.g.:

```
dropdown_field[]: dropdown_value_1
dropdown_field[]: dropdown_value_2
```

but for the all filter, and e.g. one checkbox it will be:

```
dropdown_field[]: dropdown_value_1, dropdown_value_2 .....
dropdown_field[]: dropdown_value_2
```

Unchecking the `all` checkbox will not empty the array, what it should.

That will cause the single filters not to work if `all` is checked. How can I make sure that the query request will be one array for all values instead of multiple query requests?

All Filters should be activated on load, the `all` filter would be disabled then. If a single checkbox is checked `all` shouldn't be checked (array has to be empty except the single value).

```
{% set dropdown_field = ['dropdown_value_1', 'dropdown_value_2', 'dropdown_value_3', 'dropdown_value_4', 'dropdown_value_5'] %}

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries({
    dropdown_field: dropdown_field,
    section: 'section_1',
}) %}

<div s-replace="#results">
    <div>
        <input sprig type="checkbox" name="dropdown_field[]" id="dropdown_value_all" value="" {{ dropdown_field|length >= 5 ? 'checked disabled' : '' }}>
        <label for="dropdown_value_all">
            Select All Values
        </label>
    </div>
    {% for value in dropdown_field %}
    <div>
        <input sprig type="checkbox" name="dropdown_field[]" id="{{ value }}" value="{{ value }}" {{ value in dropdown_field ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label for="{{ value }}">
            {{ value }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div id="results">
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entryQuery %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to give the `Select All Values` checkbox a unique name. That way, you can easily detect whether it was selected or not. You should also break `dropdown_field` out into 2 variables to avoid confusion.

```
{% set select_all_values = select_all_values ?? false

{% set dropdown_field_options = ['dropdown_value_1', 'dropdown_value_2', 'dropdown_value_3', 'dropdown_value_4', 'dropdown_value_5'] %}
{% set params = {section: 'section_1'} %}

{% if not select_all_values %}
    {% set params = params|merge({dropdown_field: dropdown_field} %}
{% endif %}

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries(params) %}


<div s-replace="#results">
    <div>
        <input sprig type="checkbox" name="select_all_values" id="dropdown_value_all" value="1" {{ select_all_values ? 'checked disabled' : '' }}>
        <label for="dropdown_value_all">
            Select All Values
        </label>
    </div>
    {% for value in dropdown_field_options %}
    <div>
        <input sprig type="checkbox" name="dropdown_field[]" id="{{ value }}" value="{{ value }}" {{ value in dropdown_field ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label for="{{ value }}">
            {{ value }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ben!!